# List items alphabeticaly in MySql query

Tags: mysql

I have items in a MySql field that are in the format such as: `FK1` `FK2` `FK3` up to `FK1000`. What is happening is when I run `UPDATE` query like the one below, it updates items like `FK10` and `FK100`. I am trying to just update items from `FK1` to `FK20` using the between statement. Why is it also updating item `FK101`,  `FK102` etc.

```
UPDATE `boxes`
SET intake_date = '2015-12-17 10:09:11'
WHERE customer = 'demo'
AND custref BETWEEN 'fk1' AND 'fk20';
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE `boxes` SET intake_date = '2015-12-17 10:09:11' WHERE customer = 'demo' AND cast(substring(custref, 3) AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

It strips off the leading FK, and converts to integer so order is correct.

Comment: Edited to full query as per your original

Comment: Could I ask Paul, what does the custref, 3 relate to. Thanks

Comment: Just added a comment to that - the integer part starts at character 3 in the string.

Comment: Can this also be used safely in a select query. Thanks

Comment: I tested it as a query rather than an update, so yes

Comment: I have just run this query and it throws an error. Have I got the statement correct.Thanks. SELECT * FROM `boxes` where customer = 'demo' AND cast(substring(custref, 3) AS SIGNED)) BETWEEN fk1 AND fk20;

Comment: the end part should be _BETWEEN 1 AND 20_  not _BETWEEN fk1 AND fk20_ as you are now comparing integers

Comment: You included an extra ) but returns no results.

Comment: didn't spot the extra )

Comment: Sorry paul, but I am experiencing some weird behavior with your statement. Say I have 144 items in a field numbered 1 to 144. When I run the statement it only lists .items up to 99. Why is this. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81438/discussion-between-paulf-and-user1532468).

Comment: That is OK Paul. Think I sorted it. Used a limit statement and that returned the results. Phew. Many thanks for offer.